# Dirac Spinors as Eigenvalues of Helicity Matrix

Tags: dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, helicity

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to verify this relation regarding the helicity of Dirac spinors:
$$
{ \sigma  }_{ \vec { p }  }u_{ r }\left( \vec { p }  \right) =\frac { \vec { \Sigma  } \cdot \vec { p }  }{ \left| \vec { p }  \right|  } u_{ r }\left( \vec { p }  \right) =\left( -1 \right) ^{ r+1 }u_{ r }\left( \vec { p }  \right) 
$$
Further details can be found in the book by F.Mandl and G.Shaw "Quantum Field Theory" at page 60 equation 4.35. I am using the [Dirac representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Dirac_basis) for the Gamma Matrices but I am starting wondering if this relation could be representation dependent (I have tried also to compute it in the [Weyl representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Weyl_.28chiral.29_basis) but again unsuccessfully). I calculated it both by hand and using Mathematica with the same negative outcome.

I noticed that this equation is valid if one assumes to be in the reference frame in which the impulse p is directed along the z axis p = (0,0,p3).

My questions are:
is that relation dependent of the gamma matrices representation?
is that relation dependent of the reference frame?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that ["derive this equation for me"](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5968/25301) type questions are considered off-topic. Could you rephrase your question to be more about the concept that's troubling you, rather than about the mathematics involved?

Comment: I am sorry, this is the first time I am asking something. I will take more care in future.